# Error when using generics with multiple generic constrains

Tags: c#, generics

I've inherited an application consisting of a basic framework of which I have no control over. Now some classes have changed there and I have to update our usage of it.

The basic framework is relying heavily on generics. Now I have a certain problem when using them. This code represents the problem in a simplified way:

```
class MainClass<T, U, V> 
    where T : ClassA<U, V> , new()
    where U : ClassB<V>, new() 
    where V : ClassC
{
    void AddSomething()
    {
        U myU = new U();
        myU.Data = new ClassCImpl();

        // "Cannot convert source type ClassCImpl to target type V"
    }

    void AddSomething2()
    {
        List<U> val = new List<U>();

        ClassB<ClassC> myClBC = new ClassB<ClassC>();
        myClBC.Data = new ClassCImpl();

        val.Add(myClBC);

        // "Argument type ClassB<ClassC> is not assignable to U"
    }
}
```

The framework classes look like this:

```
class ClassA<T, U>
    where T : ClassB<U> 
    where U : ClassC
{ }

class ClassB<T> where T : ClassC
{
    public virtual T Data {get; set;}
}

abstract class ClassC { }

class ClassCImpl : ClassC { }
```

The code is currently used as in the Method `AddSomething` in class `MainClass`. This code throws the error *"Cannot convert source type ClassEImpl to target type V"*. I thought that this might be related to `ClassCImpl` being not the exact type as in the generic constraint of type `ClassC`. So I tried to use `AddSomething2`, as I don't need it necessarily generic there. But, this throws the error *"Argument type ClassB is not assignable to U"*, but I thought `ClassB<ClassC>` is exactly what `U` is.

Now I am wondering, where is the error in my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that `ClassCImpl` is compatible with the `T` of your `ClassB<T>`.

Suppose I have:

```
public class OtherClassC : ClassC {}
...
MainClass mc = new MainClass<ClassB<OtherClassC>, OtherClassC>();
mc.AddSomething();
```

That's going to try to set a `ClassCImpl` value to a property of type `OtherClassC`. That's not going to work.

Likewise your `AddSomething2` method would try to add a `ClassB<ClassC>` to a `List<ClassB<OtherClassC>>` - again, that's not valid.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but when you start trying to use specific concrete types within your `AddSomething` methods, you're likely to have problems. You should possibly try making some of this code *less* generic - aside from anything else, that would make it simpler to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that helped quite a lot, as I noticed that my main problem was that I actually didn't know what I needed and so I made flawed assumptions. 

I solved my problem by putting in a few thoughts about what I actually need, and noticed it was nothing more than a way to create instances of ClassC in the code, so adding new() to the generic constraints was all that was necessary. Now I wish I would have made these extra thoughts before writing.

Thanks for your help!